# Arcpy - (Error 999999) Table Already Exists Project Management

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, error-999999

My code is supposed to clip features within a temporary directory, project them and place them into a specific feature dataset within a geodatabase. Then the code goes back and deletes the temporary files in the temporary directory.

The code runs through a list to do this. The first iteration through works flawlessly but when the second iteration begins I receive the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Q:\Admin\AOI_Generator\Scripts\Create_AOI_v1.1_Pick.py", line 219, in 
    arcpy.Project_management(temp + '\' + fc + "_" + ds + ".shp", data + "\" + ds + "\" + fc, outCS)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7822, in Project
    raise e
ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
The table already exists.
Failed to execute (Project).

I already know that the error occurs during the project_management, I am just unsure why it happens.

Please see the code below.

```
for buff, ds in n_list:
    def listFcsInGDB(gdb):
            env.workspace = gdb
            fcs = []
            for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:
                    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
                            fcs.append(os.path.join(fds,fc))
            return fcs
    fcs = listFcsInGDB(gdb)
    for fc in fcs:

            arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,r"Q:\\Admin\\AOI_Generator\\Shapefiles\\Buffer\\" + buff, temp + '\\' + fc + "_" + ds)
            arcpy.Project_management(temp + '\\' + fc + "_" + ds + ".shp", data + "\\" + ds + "\\" + fc, outCS)
            arcpy.Delete_management(temp + '\\' + fc + "_" + ds + ".shp")
    del fcs
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, so I refactored the code a bit. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
def listFcsInGDB(gdb):
    env.workspace = gdb
    fcs = []
    for fds in arcpy.ListDatasets('','feature') + ['']:
        for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','',fds):
            fcs.append(os.path.join(fds,fc))
    return fcs


fcs = listFcsInGDB(gdb)

for buff, ds in n_list:
for fc in fcs:
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(fc,r"Q:\\Admin\\AOI_Generator\\Shapefiles\\Buffer\\" + buff, temp + '\\' + fc + "_" + ds)
    arcpy.Project_management(temp + '\\' + fc + "_" + ds + ".shp", data + "\\" + ds + "\\" + fc, outCS)
    arcpy.Delete_management(temp + '\\' + fc + "_" + ds + ".shp")
del fcs
```